# Ledpar: Does the function "ledgroup" work with ledpar

Tags: footnotes, ledmac

Setting a critical editions of (Greek) fragments with facing translations works fine with `ledmac` and `ledpar`. Even the critical apparatuses (up to 3) are there (at the bottom of the page).

Now I have to set a bundle of fragments with the apparatuses (?) right beneath the concerning fragment, then followed by the next fragment/apparatuses and so on.

With `ledmac` (without facing translations) one can use `minipage`/`ledgroup` which - again - works fine.

But I (or `ledpar` - I don't hope so) am not able to use `\begin{ledgroup} ... \end{ledgroup}` in my parallel version.

Here a minimum example:

```
\documentclass{scrbook}
\usepackage{ledmac,ledpar}  
\setcounter{firstlinenum}{1}    
\setcounter{linenumincrement}{1}
\begin{document}

\begin{pages}
\begin{Leftside}
\beginnumbering
\pstart
\edtext{This is a sample text.}{\Afootnote{A secondary footnote}} 
\pend

\endnumbering
\end{Leftside}

\begin{Rightside}

\beginnumbering

\pstart
On this page there is supposed to be the translation of the left page.
\pend

\endnumbering
\end{Rightside}

\Pages
\end{pages}

\end{document}
```

Has anyone some (or better lots of) experience with `ledpar` and an idea how this problem could be solved?

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.sx!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/1436/welcome-to-tex-sx) A tip: You can use backticks `\`` to [mark your inline code](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/863/how-do-i-mark-inline-code) as I did in my edit.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is solved. Maïeul Rouquette has modified the `ledpar`-package. Now it works. It will be uploaded on CTAN within the next days.

Answer (score 1):

I don't know if it is what you wish, but you can have parallel columns on a minipage..., like this for instance :

```
\begin{minipage}{16.5cm}
\begin{pairs} 
\begin{Leftside} 
\beginnumbering 
\pstart 
\edtext{This is a sample text.}{\Afootnote{A secondary footnote}} 
\pend 
\endnumbering 
\end{Leftside} 
\begin{Rightside} 
\beginnumbering 
\pstart 
On this page there is supposed to be the translation of the left page. 
\pend 
\endnumbering 
\end{Rightside} 
\Columns 
\end{pairs} 
\end{minipage}
```

Comment: That is not exactly what I wish. I need facing pages not columns. The minipage-env does not work in that way with `\begin{pages}` and `\end{pages}` because there are pagebreaks (I think). "Normal" TeX-footnotes work in my example, but the Afootnotes etc. not :-(